# How can I remove the default browser favorites?

Tags: browser, customization

The default browser on my Galaxy S Vibrant running Froyo has a bunch of favorites pre-loaded -- CNN, Facebook, etc.  The browser tells me they can't be deleted when I try.  How can I delete them?  Is there a folder of them somewhere I can just delete?  I am rooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Doing a full `Clear Data` on the default browser (*"Internet" on the Incredible*) worked for me. Just make sure you have your other bookmarks backed up (for example, using an app such as [Backup Bookmarks](https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.eguchi.android.bookmarkbackup&feature=search_result) could be used to back them up to SD). The steps should look something like this:</s>

Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > All > Internet > Clear Data

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comment below, [Bookmarks Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.guenmat.android.bookmarks) allows users to delete the default browser favorites/bookmarks. Note that the crossed-out portion of this answer would erase things such as history, entered text, etc. however, apparently not the default bookmarks.

Comment: Unfortunately, after clearing data I actually have *more* undeletable bookmarks than before.

Comment: Very strange... can you delete them using this app? [Bookmarks Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.guenmat.android.bookmarks) (longpress > delete). Not sure why Clear Data generated *more* undeletable bookmarks but it seems like that is a wrong answer. Let me know if this works...

Comment: Bookmarks Manager did it, thanks.  +1.  I assume the browser has some sort of "initial setup" where it restores those bookmarks or something.